# Question was removed before I could provide clarification

Tags: support, deleted-questions

My Inbox today had an alert to a comment on a question, where it seems some clarification was being asked for in order to make the question more useful.  However, when trying to view the comment, I see the question was deleted.

As I'm not among the elite high-rep users who can view such questions, I have no way to correct the issue.

Could somebody please clarify for me:

1. Why the question was deleted, when there was a recently opened request for clarification?
2. What can I do to restore the question?

Since I can no longer view the question, I can't say definitively whether or not it had any answers that were useful to me - or would have been of *any* use to anyone else - but I do believe it did.

Link from my Inbox is below:

https://superuser.com/posts/comments/500299

Comment: There were no answers.

Answer (score 4):

You were the first to Vote to close the question. You'd left an explicit comment:

> "Voted to close. This is no longer really an issue in current versions of Firefox".

The most recent comment was:

> You also didn't mention which version of Firefox, so this question is useless now.

Considering you had voted to close & it was a year old and nowit's no longer an issue, I didn't see any reason why it should be around and deleted it.

If you're curious, here's the full question:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Wow.  That vote was so old, I'd totally forgotten about it.  Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @IsziRoryorIsznti you're welcome.